# BJQS bad rendering for the first loop

Tags: html, css, bjqs

Hy, I want to create a slider with 4 articles (4 movie reviews) and everything works fine, but one thing: when I load the web page, rendering is bad for the first time. I mean, it loads all image and data over the elements and thanks to "max-content" data width, I see elements that are longer than the first child. See it [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d79SY.png)

But after I click through all the 4 child with the prev or after button, I see it properly, so the problem is with just the first loop. Like [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3b7m.png) - Now, I don't see other child's title and subtitle.

What can be the problem?

HTML:

```
<blh:head_required />
<blh:body_required />
<div id="page-wrapper" class="container {blh:post_inside hyphen="1"}">

  <!-- HEADER -->

  <header class="coffee_row">
    <div class="coffee_header">
      <div class="coffee_header_headline">
        <center><a href="https://smokingbarrels.blog.hu/"><img src="http://m.blog.hu/sm/smokingbarrels/skins/sb2019/img/smokingb_title3.png" /></center></a>
        <h3><blh:blog_tagline /></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="nav_mobile_menu_icon">
      <span id="mobile_nav_btn">

     </span>
    </div>
    <div class="coffee_header_line"></div>
    <div class="coffee_header_nav">
      <blh:menu />
      <hr>
      <p></p>

      <blhc:if key="pageType" value="blogcimlap" operator="eq">
            <blh:starred width="980" height="450" limit="4" bjqs_showcontrols="true"                                       bjqs_showmarkers="false" bjqs_centermarkers="false" article-subtitle="true" />
        <center>&#11044; &#11044; &#11044;</center>
        </blhc:if>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- /HEADER -->


  <!-- CONTENT SIDE -->
    <section id="content-side">
        <div class="coffee_content_side coffee_row">

            <blhc:postloop>

                <article id="{blh:post_slug}" class="post post_{blh:post_ogg cols="1"} {blh:post_visibility} {blh:post_dtype} {blh:post_increment} coffee_article
                   {blhc:if key="pageType" value="post" operator="ne"}coverpage{/blhc:if}
                   {blhc:if key="pageType" value="post" operator="eq"}postpage {/blhc:if} " lang="{blh:post_lang}">

                <div class="coffee_post_content">

                        <blhc:if key="pageType" value="post" operator="ne">
                            <div class="coffee_post_img">
                                <a href="{blh:post_permalink}">
                                    <blh:post_first_img width="310" height="auto" resize="0" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </blhc:if>

                        <div class="coffee_post_container">
                            <div class="coffee_post_title">
                                <a href="{blh:post_permalink}">
                                    <blh:post_title/>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <blhc:if key="pageType" value="blogcimlap" operator="ne">
                                <div class="coffee_post_subtitle">
                                    <blh:post_subtitle/>
                                </div>
                            </blhc:if>

                          <div class="coffee_post_meta">
                                By:
                                <span class="author"><blh:post_author /></span>
                                <span class="date"><blh:post_date format="Y. M d."/></span>
                                <span class="edit"><blh:post_edit/></span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="coffee_post_entry">
                                <blh:post_content length="500" cutoff="..." />
                            </div>

                            <div class="share">
                                <blh:share />
                            </div>

                            <blhc:if key="pageType" value="post" operator="eq">
                                <blh:post_trbrdf/>

                                <blh:post_feedback/>
                            </blhc:if>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </article>

            </blhc:postloop>

           <!-- pager -->
            <div class="coffee_pager_wrap">
              <div class="coffee_pager">
                  <blh:pager prelabel="előző oldal" nxtlabel="következő oldal" />
              </div>
            </div>

    <div class="coffee_widget_wrap">
            <div id="<blhc:if key="pageType" value="post" operator="ne">coffee_widgets</blhc:if>"
                class="coffee_widgets <blhc:if key="pageType" value="post"                 operator="ne">coverpage</blhc:if>
                <blhc:if key="pageType" value="post" operator="eq">postpage</blhc:if> ">
                <blh:social />
                <blh:rightboxes />
            </div>
            </div>



        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /CONTENT SIDE -->

</div>
<!-- /PAGE WRAPPER -->

<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer></footer>
<!-- /FOOTER -->
<script src="https://m.blog.hu/skins/novo_art/scripts/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://m.blog.hu/skins/coffee/js/jquery_dotdotdot_min.js?v=20180914"></script>
<script src="https://m.blog.hu/skins/coffee/js/coffee_handler.js?v=20180914"></script>
```

CSS:

```
#slider {
background: #b00538;
width: 1050px;
height: 400px;
margin: 0 0 20px;
padding: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
}

#slider:hover .article-data {
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}

#slider:hover img {
  color: white;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#slider .article-infos,
#slider .lead {
display: none;
}

#slider .bjqs {
display: block;
position: relative;
width: 1050px;
height: 400px;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#slider .bjqs li {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
  background-color: #b00538;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 770px;
    height: 410px;
}

#slider .article-image {
display: block;
background: #0f0f22;
position: relative;
width: 1023px;
height: 450px;
}

#slider img {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
height: auto;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: auto
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in 0s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in 0s;

}

#slider .article-data {
background: transparent;
position: relative;
bottom: 135px;
left: 0px;
font-size: 30px;
padding: 0;
width: auto;
overflow: hidden;
height: auto;
}

#slider .article-data h1 {
    padding: 1px 15px 15px;
  background: #b00538;
  color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
    overflow: visible:
    word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-word;
  width: max-content;
    height: 30px;
}

#slider .article-data h1 a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: auto;
}

#slider .article-data h2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
  left: 0px;
    padding: 0px 15px 15px;
  background: white;
  color: #1a1a3d;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
    overflow: visible:
    word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-word;
    width: max-content;
    height: 50px;
}

#slider .article-data h2 a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: auto;
}

#slider .bjqs-markers {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 35px;
right: -345px;
width: 345px;
z-index: 5;
}

#slider .bjqs-markers li { 
    background: #cfcfcf;
    font-family: Playfair Display;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0 0 2px;
}

#slider .bjqs-markers li + li + li + li + li {
    display: none;
}

    #slider .bjqs-markers li.active-marker {
        background: #353535;
    }

#slider .bjqs-markers a {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    z-index: 2;
}

    #slider .bjqs-markers a:hover {
        background: #b7b5b5;
        color: #000;
    }

    #slider .bjqs-markers .active-marker a {
        background: #353535;
        color: #fff;
    }

#slider .bjqs-markers .active-marker {
    position: relative;
}

#slider .bjqs-markers .active-marker:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: #353535;
    border-width: 28px;
    margin-top: -28px;
}

#slider ul.bjqs-controls {
display: block;
position: relative;
top: -350px;
width: 100%;
font-family: Arimo;
z-index: 10;
}

#slider ul.bjqs-controls li {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 65px
    color: white;
}

    #slider ul.bjqs-controls li a {
        background: #b00538;
      position: relative;
      padding: 0px 0px 58px;
        display: block;
        color: white;
        font-size: 55px;
        line-height: 50px;
      font-weight: bold;
        opacity: 0.9;
        font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    }

        .bjqs-prev a:after,
        .bjqs-next a:after {
            content: none;
        }

#slider ul.bjqs-controls .bjqs-next {
  background: #b00538;
  color: white;
    right: 10px;
}

#slider ul.bjqs-controls .bjqs-prev {
  background:  #b00538;
  color: white;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: That is not valid html. Guess you are using some kind of framework?

Comment: I just copied the slider-relevant parts of the HTML, but I copied the whole to the original post

Comment: elements like `blhc` are not standard html. My guess is that you use some kind of framework that transforms these elements to the sliders from the jQuery plugin since you didnt post the javascript code to initiate the plugin either. You should use a tag of the framework you use so people with knowledge about this can check your question.

Comment: I just use a template, so I don't know about Jquery plugin or anything else. You can see at the end of the HTML that it contains some .JS files. I opened them, but I just don't know what to do with them. I don't know if I have to change something in these files...

Comment: html doesn't have templates by itself. Are you using wordpress?

Comment: I don't know, it's similiar to Wordpress, but not exactly I guess. In Hungary, there is a huge site called blog.hu, where you can create a blog for yourself and can use the built-in templates. In the given templates, you can edit the HTML, CSS and JS files

Comment: I think your best bet is to contact blog.hu about it then.

Comment: I did, but they can't help me if I edit the template radically which I did (this template don't even contains a slider.)